# Highlight "Cannot find name" / "any" in Vs Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code, when I make mistake in Typescript it highlights the error as "Cannot find name" / any, but in Javascript it is assigned "any" and therefore it is not an highlighted. Image attached:
[image: javascript vs typescript]

Is it possible to highlight in JavaScript the errors in same way? JSlint extension did not help. It would be painful to see the errors only in build.

Comment: I have installed the ESLint extension and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. I disabled all extensions and kept only ESLint but it still does not work

Comment: TypeScript 2.3 included an option to [type check JS files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files). But this is something any linter will catch and there are many VSCode plugins to do this. Perhaps the issue is with extension configuration?

Comment: It seems I am unable to set up normal lint for some reason. So I installed https://github.com/ricardofbarros/linter-js-standard , which just enforces its settings automatically and then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript by default squelches these errors when you're in a `.js` file - however, if you add a `// @ts-check` comment to the top of your `.js` file, then you should get a similar form of checking as you would in TypeScript.

This is fairly new, but you can get details on it [from the official blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/04/27/announcing-typescript-2-3/).

The summary is

1. Either add a `// @ts-check` comment to the top of your file, or
2. add the `checkJs` option to your `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json`

Answer (score -1):

Need console.log(result).
But  console.log(esult)

Comment: Please read the question instead of just looking at the picture.